# powerbuilder appeon mobile web. how to determine a url link is returning a 404

Tags: powerbuilder

When using a picture control on a appeon mobile web, how do you determine that the picture name url is returning a 404 error, file not found error?
Example code line: p_picture.picturename = "http://myurl.org/picture.jpg"
tia

Comment: did you check the document yet?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the GetUrl function of the inet object. You can find the string "404 - File or directory not found" in the return content if the 404 error occurred.

Please refer to the simple PB case below for details.
http://demo.appeon.com/ear/geturl.zip

Regards,
ZhaoKai